# Незадача с созданием цикла.

Tags: java

Никак не могу додуматься, как решить данную задачу.

```
void matrix(int n){

}
```

Например, если n = 2, то выводит

```
*1*
121
*1*
```

если n = 4, то выводит

```
***1***
**121**
*12321*
1234321
*12321*
**121**
***1***
```

Знаю, что спрашивать решение не положено, по этому попрошу подсказок. 
Пробовал в способ многомерного массива, но дальше, чем заполнить его звездочками, ниче не выходит. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, всё на самом деле не так сложно.

Пускай вам надо вывести 1-ю строку. Сколько в ней звёздочек вначале? Подумайте. Затем идёт 1, затем столько же звёздочек. Хорошо.

Следующая строка: звёздочек меньше — на сколько? Что выводится за ними? И сколько звёздочек в конце.

Дальше обобщайте сами. Надеюсь, это подтолкнёт вас к правильной идее.